# Replace index.php?p=sites with a name

Tags: php, .htaccess, replace, hyperlink

I'm trying in the .htaccess-file to replace index.php?p=sites with a name, for example instead of

```
www.sitename.com/index.php?p=help -> www.sitename.com/help/
```

I still have no solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess should be like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

And PHP will get this link www.sitename.com/help/ as www.sitename.com/index.php?p=help
So you can get p as $_GET['p']

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. I have insert the code into the .htaccess-file but the **www.sitename.com/index.php?p=help** site can't be called with **www.sitename.com/help/** - I don't understand what you are meaning with the `$_GET['p']`, I think this is why the link (www.sitename.com/help/) isn't working. :/

Comment: Rewright works 100%. But You need to be sure then your .htaccess file works well. Try to put in top of .htaccess file --> deny from all. This should block all access to website

Comment: The file works well. But it isn't working.. has it something to do with `$_GET['p']` as you already wrote above? I didn't unterstand that..

Comment: No, you can ignore $_GET['p'] if you just need to rewright URL. I describe how to get this var in PHP if you will be needed. But seems you don't need it now, and you have already working code. Andyou need just rewright